# I want my character in pygame to not go off the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a simple platformer in pygame where the player will return to the begging of the window if they go to far to the right.  However, my code is not working and the player is able to go off the screen and does not return to the start.  This is my code so far:

```py
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30,40))
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (width /2, height /2)
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.pos = 480

    def update(self):
        self.speed_x = 0
        player_input = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if player_input[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.speed_x = -5

        if player_input[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speed_x = 5

        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y

        # wrap around the sides of the screen
        if self.pos > 480:
            self.pos  = 0
        if self.pos < 0:
            self.pos = -480,0
```

Comment: are you sure that you correctly center you sprite? self.rect.center = (width/2, height/2) are you sure for this? you need to position this according to the window coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` rather than `self.pos`

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use the `%` (modulo) operator. The `%` (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. See [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

For instance:

```py
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):

        # [...]

        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y

        rect.centerx = rect.centerx % width
        rect.centery = rect.centery % height
```

Answer (score 0):

when you move the player, you change `self.rect.x`, but not change `self.pos`, so when you move off the screen, `self.pos` will still = 480, so you want to check if `self.rect.x` is off the screen, then reset that.

```
# wrap around the sides of the screen
if self.rect.x > 480:
    self.rect.x  = 0
if self.rect.x < 0:
    self.rect.x = 480
```